# Prove that $p(x)=d(x,0)$ is not a seminorm

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a topological vector space and $\{p_1,p_2,\dots\}$ be a nondecreasing family of seminorms on $E$. Define $$d(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \frac{p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)},$$
where $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i<\infty$.

> **My question:** How to prove that $p(x)=d(x,0)$ is not a seminorm?

It's easy to see that $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)$. Thus, the property that must fail is homogeneity, that is, $p(\lambda x) = |\lambda| p(x)$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and all $x \in E$. We have, $$p(\lambda x)= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \frac{p_i(\lambda x)}{1+p_i(\lambda x)}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \frac{|\lambda|p_i(x)}{1+|\lambda|p_i( x)}.$$

What algebraic manipulation could I do to get $p(\lambda x)\neq |\lambda|p(x)|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any $x$ such that there exists $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p_i(x) > 0$. Then for $|\lambda| > 1$,
$$p(\lambda x) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j \frac{|\lambda|p_j(x)}{1+|\lambda|p_j( x)} < \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{a_j |\lambda|p_j(x)}{1+p_j(x)} = |\lambda|p(x)$$
since $1+|\lambda|p_j(x) \geq 1 + p_j(x)$ for all $j$ and $1+|\lambda|p_i(x) > 1 + p_i(x)$.

Comment: It shouldn't be $\leq$? since the summation is a limit process.

Comment: No, the inequality is strict. There is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $a_i \frac{|\lambda|p_i(x)}{1 + |\lambda| p_i(x)|} < \frac{a_i |\lambda|p_i(x)}{1 + p_i(x)} - \varepsilon$.

Comment: I didn't understand why the last equality is valid. Could you give any more details?

Comment: I'd misread the definition of $p$, apologies. Should now be fixed.

Comment: I still couldn't see how to use the inequality $a_i\frac{|\lambda|p_i(x)}{1+|\lambda|p_i(x)}< a_i\frac{|\lambda|p_i(x)}{1+p_i(x)}-\varepsilon$ to have the strict inequality.

Comment: For $N > i$ you have that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j \frac{|\lambda|p_j(x)}{1+|\lambda|p_j( x)} < \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{a_j |\lambda|p_j(x)}{1+p_j(x)} - \varepsilon$$
Now send $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Perfect, now I understand.